# Form to edit specific instance of model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I know this question has been asked before but I have read through the answers and none of them sufficed. I am trying to make a job board site, where an employer can sign up and post jobs. So there is an `Employer` object and each employer can post as many `Job`s as they want. I am not sure how to create a form where a particular model instance can be edited.

The model `Job`:

```
poster = models.ForeignKey(Employer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    establishment_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    details = models.TextField(max_length = 2000)
    salary = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    state_choices = (
         #long list omitted on purpose 
)
    state = models.CharField(choices=state_choices, max_length = 20)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length = 10)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.job_title + " - " + self.establishment_name \
               + ", " + self.poster.user.first_name + " " +self.poster.user.last_name
```

I have a form to post jobs:

```
class JobPostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields= ('job_title',
                 'establishment_name',
                 'details',
                 'address',
                 'city',
                 'state',
                 'zip_code',
               )
```

a view to post jobs:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = JobPostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        job_object = form.save(commit=False)
        job_object.poster = request.user.employer
        job_object.save()
        return redirect('employer_home')


else:
    form = JobPostForm()
```

and a template to post jobs:

```
<form method="post" class="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p}}
  <button type="submit">Post Job</button>
</form>
```

but am not sure how to create something that can edit a job post. I have seen examples using `UpdateView()` but could not get that to work. Does anyone know how to get this to work for this particular instance?

Comment: Using `UpdateView` should just be as simple as specifying the form class that you're using to update, and ensuring that `pk` is part of the URL's kwargs. If you don't want to have the pk in the URL, you can override `get_object` in the view class to obtain the object by whatever means necessary for your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [UpdateWiew](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview)

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
class JobUpdateView(UpdateView) 
    model = Job
    form_class = JobPostForm
    template_name = "Jobform.html"

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
       job = get_object_or_404(Job, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
       return job

    def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
       return reverse("ulr_name_to_redirect_after_success")
```